MS ACCESS - Insert into is not inserting variable values
This is all about bill of materials on parts.. The problem I've hit is when a child part has its own bill of materials I need to transfer it to the top level part
In the below code... I've selected everything needed, the recordset count holds the correct amount of records,  it loops through assigning the correct values to the variables for each record.
The problem is the RqPrtNum & RqPrtLnk variables don't insert there values into the table in the INSERT INTO. They hold the correct value but instead I get a pop up asking me what the value is...
    strSQL2 = "SELECT tbl_BOM_Requirments.PrtNmber_LinkField, tbl_BOM_Requirments.RequiredMaterialPrtNum, tbl_BOM_Requirments.RequiredMaterialDescription, tbl_BOM_Requirments.ReqrdQty, tbl_BOM_Requirments.MstrBomFreeIssue, tbl_BOM_Requirments.MstrBomPlySize, tbl_BOM_Requirments.MstrBomPlyQty, tbl_BOM_Requirments.MstrBomUnitCost, tbl_BOM_Requirments.MstrBomTotalPrice, tbl_BOM_Requirments.MstrBomPlyTotal " & vbCrLf & _
"FROM tbl_BOM_Requirments " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE (((tbl_BOM_Requirments.PrtNmber_LinkField)=""PRT1229""));"

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL2)
With rs
If rs.EOF Then
      FindRecordCount = 0
   Else
      rs.MoveLast
      FindRecordCount = rs.RecordCount
      rs.MoveFirst
   End If
   
Do Until rs.EOF
    If Not rs.EOF Then
     RqPrtNum = rs![RequiredMaterialPrtNum]
        RqPrtLnk = rs![PrtNmber_LinkField]

    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Tbl_BOM_Requirments ([RequiredMaterialPrtNum],[PrtNmber_LinkField]) VALUES( RqPrtNum ,  RqPrtLnk )"
    End If
rs.MoveNext    
Loop    
End With

Any ideas why when RqPrtNum & RqPrtLnk are being watched the values are correct but there not being inserted into the table ?
If I key the value into the pop up it inserts into the table..

You want to insert the actual value and not trigger the prompting of unknown field values.
Try
"INSERT INTO Tbl_BOM_Requirments ([RequiredMaterialPrtNum],[PrtNmber_LinkField]) VALUES( '" & RqPrtNum & "','" &  RqPrtLnk & "')"


Other ways to handle it is via a saved QueryDef  see https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/set-query-parameter-from-vba.294246/

Hi Bart, That's got the RqPrtNum working. The RqPrtLnk still came up with a popup only the text in the pop had changed from RqPrtLnk to PRT1229... if i keyed in a value into the pop up nothing got inserted into the table. But if i left  " & RqPrtNum & " as you suggested , put the back " &  RqPrtLnk &" to just RqPrtLnk the pop up appeared for only  RqPrtLnk and the both the keyed in value and  RqPrtNum got inserted into the table... so its now only the RqPrtLnk that's not working....  (thanks for your help on this.... its been driving me nuts)

Check that your literals are properly delimited. Use a variable with a name like strSQL to hold long or constructed queries like this. The do DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL. Put a break-point on this line. Then step thru your running code using the debugger. What do you see when you evaluate the query string within your immediate window? it should be like INSERT INTO Tbl_BOM_Requirments ([RequiredMaterialPrtNum],[PrtNmber_LinkField]) VALUES( '123','abc')

In your expression
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Tbl_BOM_Requirments ([RequiredMaterialPrtNum],[PrtNmber_LinkField]) VALUES( RqPrtNum ,  RqPrtLnk )"

values (variables) RqPrtNum ,  RqPrtLnk undefined. In this case you  get a pop up asking  what the value is.
See example for MS Access query with parameters:
strSql3 = "PARAMETERS RqPrtNum long,  RqPrtLnk string;" _
        & " INSERT INTO Tbl_BOM_Requirments" _
        & " ([RequiredMaterialPrtNum],[PrtNmber_LinkField])" _
        & " values (RqPrtNum ,  RqPrtLnk);"
    Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSql3)
    qdf("RqPrtNum") = RqPrtNum
    qdf("RqPrtLnk") = RqPrtLnk
    qdf.Execute (dbFailOnError)



Another suggestion is to execute 1 query instead of executing all of this VBA looping code.
DoCmd.RunSQL "
    INSERT INTO Tbl_BOM_Requirments ([RequiredMaterialPrtNum],[PrtNmber_LinkField]) 
    SELECT RequiredMaterialPrtNum, 
           PrtNmber_LinkField 
    FROM tbl_BOM_Requirments 
    WHERE PrtNmber_LinkField='PRT1229'
    "

